# GL incompatibility with Worldwind software when running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: drivers, 22.04, graphics, intel, opengl

When Trying to run the software Worldwind in my machine, I find the following message on the screen:

[Error when trying to run Worldwind](https://i.stack.imgur.com/beuSA.png)

Does anyone know if Ubuntu has updated drivers regarding Intel Iris Xe? If so, I think that will make possible the proper functioning of Worldwind or any other software with similar graphic requirements.

Follows the Graphic Board configuration of my notebook:

[image: Graphic Board configuration and drivers]

Comment: Please post the output of `eglinfo`